# How to access system folder in android without rooted?

Tags: android, system, rooted-device

I'm unable to access system folder in android without rooted the device. Also wanted to know is it possible to access while booting the android phone?

Answer (score 1):

**I think ur asking without doing rooting**

so Without rooting you have 2 options:

1. If the application is debuggable you can use the `run-as` command in adb shell

   ```
   adb shell
   run-as com.your.packagename 
   cp /data/data/com.your.pacakagename/
   ```
2. You can use Android's backup function.

   ```
   adb backup -noapk com.your.packagename
   ```

   You will now be prompted to 'unlock your device and confirm the backup operation'. It's best NOT to provide a password, otherwise it becomes more difficult to read the data. Just click on 'backup my data'. The resulting 'backup.ab' file on your computer contains all application data in android backup format. Basically it's a compressed tar file. [This page](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html) explains how you can use OpenSSL's zlib command to uncompress it. 
   You can use the  `adb restore backup.db` command to restore the backup.

*regards maven*

Comment: Sometimes the app [is not debuggable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61162442/4970442)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

The user that launchs the application must be root in order to access some folders. If doesn't have permissions to access a directory you cannot access to it. It's a UNIX security measurement, you can't bypass it.

Answer (score 0):

Every app can access and read the `/system` folder on an Android device. It does not have to be rooted for that.